# Loading large matrix with Armadillo

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, armadillo

I have a very sparse matrix, with a density of about `0.01`, and dimensions `20000 x 500000`. I'm trying to load this in armadillo with

```
sp_mat V;
V.load(filename, coord_ascii);
```

The file format is

```
row column value
```

But this is taking way too long. Python can parse the file and fill a dictionary with it *way* faster than armadillo can create this matrix. How should I properly do this?

The matrix is going to be filled with integers.

Any advice would be appreciated!

#### Update:

This is an issue solely with Armadillo. C++ iterates the file without issue when read line by line, but assigning the values into an `arma::sp_mat` is extremely slow.

Comment: Dealing sparse matrix in C++ and Python are very different. As your matrix is very large, then this will take time in C++.

Comment: But I don't understand why there is such a huge disparity. It's almost a 100x slowdown when using C++. I fell like it would be faster to import the Python C API to call a python function that could return a map to C++ and then use the map to create the sparse matrix. This is not just armadillo: when I used ifstream I had the same slowdown.

Comment: According to the docs for Armadillo [SpMat](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#SpMat), the only supported format is `arma_binary`. So you're using unsupported code, which is probably not finished or not optimized. The documentation has a [statement](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#api_additions) on what is considered stable: _any function, class, constant or other code not explicitly described in the public API documentation is considered as part of the underlying internal implementation details, and may change or be removed without notice._

Comment: Well this is a chicken and egg problem then :/ I can't save in `arma_binary` format because I would need to build the matrix first then call save. But I also can't load the matrix because I need `arma_binary` format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The armadillo documentation specifies

> "Using batch insertion constructors is generally much faster than consecutively inserting values using element access operators"

So here is the best I could come up with

```
sp_mat get(const char *filename) {         
    vector<long long unsigned int> location_u;
    vector<long long unsigned int> location_m;
    vector<double> values;                    

    ifstream file(filename);                  
    int a, b, c;                              
    while(file >> a >> b >> c) {                                   
        location_u.push_back(a);              
        location_m.push_back(b);              
        values.push_back(c);                  
    }                                         

    umat lu(location_u);                      
    umat lm(location_m);                      
    umat location(join_rows(lu, lm).t());     

    return V(location, vec(values));                                         
}
```

It now runs at a reasonable speed, at about 1 million lines a second.

Answer (score 1):

I today encountered this very same problem when trying to load 100MB CSV using Armadillo's `.load()`. It's just too slow.

Since @Enrico Borba answered that he is doing his own file reading using std::ifstream and the result is pretty amazing, here is my own code to load a CSV file to the Armadillo's mat type using ifstream too.

For example, if you're trying to do this, it will take soo much time to load the file:

```
arma::mat A;
A.load("file.csv", arma::csv_ascii);
```

So this is an alternative, which is thousand more faster than above code:

```
arma::mat readCSV(const std::string &filename, const std::string &delimeter = ",")
{
    std::ifstream csv(filename);
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> datas;

    for(std::string line; std::getline(csv, line); ) {

        std::vector<double> data;

        // split string by delimeter
        auto start = 0U;
        auto end = line.find(delimeter);
        while (end != std::string::npos) {
            data.push_back(std::stod(line.substr(start, end - start)));
            start = end + delimeter.length();
            end = line.find(delimeter, start);
        }
        data.push_back(std::stod(line.substr(start, end)));
        datas.push_back(data);
    }

    arma::mat data_mat = arma::zeros<arma::mat>(datas.size(), datas[0].size());

    for (int i=0; i<datas.size(); i++) {
        arma::mat r(datas[i]);
        data_mat.row(i) = r.t();
    }

    return data_mat;
}
```

Then you can substitute it like below:

```
arma::mat A = readCSV("file.csv");
```